# How can I sign SQL Server index

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Although I have a index that name is DepodakiMiktar; SQL Server giving an error.

> Index 'DepodakiMiktar' on table
>   'dbo.STOK_HAREKETLERI' (specified in
>   the FROM clause) does not exist.

How can I point my index with DB name of it.

Example

```
DBNAME.dbo.Index
```

Comment: **What** are you trying to do ?? You don't need to "sign" or "define" your index in your query at all - SQL Server will automatically use it when appropriate and when it helps. Can you **show us** the query you have that causes this error??

Comment: I assume you are using an index hint. Could you post the query?

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer for sure without seeing your query, but it seems you're trying to specify an index hint in the FROM clause of your query (using WITH)?

As marc_s has said, there's very rarely any need to do this in SQL Server -- it will automatically use appropriate indexes. Drop your WITH clause.

And *please*, if you want help with a SQL error, post your SQL statement in the question.